# Too many webgl using iframe

Tags: iframe, three.js, resources, webgl

WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost.

Hi, I am trying to show some 3D models on a WordPress site and using three.js to do so. I figured the easiest way to do this was using an iframe, the 3D models are on separate pages and loaded using code blocks.
I have 10 of these code blocks, and I understand the maximum of WebGL contexts is 16. The error arises when I refresh my webpage, the previous contexts must still be active.

I am loading the same HTML file, different models are loaded my parsing their name through the URL in the Wordpress iframe. Any idea of how I can reduce resources here?

I have tried the following in a few different places.

```
renderer.dispose();
```

Comment: You can't do it via iframes. See [Multiple Canvases, Multiple Scenes](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-multiple-scenes.html) for a solution

Comment: The problem is that I am showing the threeJS content on different locations in one wordpress page. Without iframes, how do I get threeJS content on a wordpress page?

Comment: did you read the linked article? Make some elements on the page and a script that looks them up.